# Cant set cookie. Providing full code on codeSandBox of a back and a front. Does anybody see an issue. Thank you! Express + Vue 3

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, cookies, vuejs3

Here is sandBox of a back, it's very simple. One route and one controller

[back fullCode](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-hooks-eipqm?file=/server.js)

I'm not gonna provide full code of a front, is just damn simple: I created new project of a vue3, created in src folder file api and created axios instance like that :

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://arcane-reaches-79421.herokuapp.com",
    timeout: 10000,
    withCredentials: true
});

export default instance;
```

then this is my main.js file in Vue 3

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import server from "./api"

server.get("check").then((data)=> console.log(data))

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

then I see in console response is 200, all is good and that's what I get in network(it comes with cookie in a header):
[image: first img]

[image: second img]

But Jesus, THERE IS NO COOKIE IN A BROWSERRRR!! Need badly help, stuck. I'm starting thinking there is an issue with Vue 3 maybe ? Something I don't know..

Answer (score 0):

[image: that's after changing this, it gives error like that]

```
res.cookie("Cookie", "OBJ", {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? false : true
});
```